# General advanced Python question is banned with invalid reason - closed as too localized

Tags: discussion, reputation, subjective

In my opinion, moderation process sometimes fails, since soem questions, that are in my humble option good and fit for Q&A format, receive many minus points and finally judged by some users which cannot give answers as **too localized**.

Question is related to Python **module loading speed** and **related to every Python programmer** so it is **not narrow question** - [How to avoid latencies with Python module globals initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381555/puzzle-for-true-python-masters-how-to-avoid-latencies-with-python-module-global)

I think that some people give not constructive comments and finally close question before answered - what is bad practice i.e. same as degrading question with minus points if not out of scope but difficult.

1. Someone told that was bad to optimize module loading speed if not need - true but what if it need?
2. Someone compared this question about "optimizing latencies" to other question about "measuring latencies" as duplicate - both not related but same domain [How to measure Python import loading times/latencies in AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044522/how-to-measure-python-import-loading-times-latencies-in-appengine)
3. Someone told that I want delegate some work but It look I give valuable examples.

Please **revert** question if you share option that advanced questions should be not closed by people which not know the answers to question with false reason/motivation.

I think that such questions about advanced Python optimization provide a lot of value added to the site. If you disagree, that question and similar can be removed, but please provide at least detailed explanation, why.

Comment: Perhaps people are a bit put-off by your abrasive style, arrogant tone, and harshly prejudicial assumptions. You claim repeatedly that your question is "advanced" and therefore anyone who doesn't understand it must be an idiot. A common assumption made by people who ask poor questions that get closed is that the people who closed it did so because they can't answer it. Rarely is this the case: most of the time, people casting close votes on questions are actually experts in that tag. Also keep in mind that downvotes are not the same thing as close votes: either can be cast independently.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for puzzles. Meta is not the place for whining.

Comment: @CodyGray Possible that "advanced" word instead narrowing/targeting audience bring "invalid" audience and somebody was feel like "idiot" and make "revenge" :) - I will keep your advice how to deal with it. I am not care about points but if not works better not share time for such things.

Comment: The question can be rephrased in a way that's kosher, just don't phrase it as a puzzle. Although there are some grandfathered questions that are pretty much just trivia or puzzles.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd If you judge question by keywords not by content that is true - but "puzzle" is added just for fun - question is general and could be asked without keyword "puzzle" - do you expert in Python?

Comment: @prusswan Sure it could be rephrased (not know that is not kosher/right slang) - i.e. "Reducing Python multimodule loading times in to scale web application".

Comment: I cast the fifth close vote. I am a moderator, but that vote wasn't a single binding close vote. The main problem with the question is that it's in the form of a puzzle. It's not presented as a problem that can have (several) technically acceptable solutions. 'Not Constructive' might have been a better reason. I think the question could be edited to become a better fit, or perhaps re-phrased to better fit the [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) [scope](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq) and asked there. Code  Review is another possibility.

Comment: To be clear, I don't think you asked a **bad** question, the Q&A nature of SO is just not well equipped to handle that type of question.

Comment: I'm an expert in whining; does that count? Seriously, are you interested in getting constructive suggestions and feedback here? Or do you just want to vent your frustration and assert your superior intelligence? Yes, phrasing of your question is important, that's one of the things that people judge it based on. We might be able to offer suggestions on how to fix or improve your question if you're actually interested in those, but such doesn't appear to be the case. You're just looking for re-open votes, but that's unlikely to happen with an attitude to go along with it.

Comment: @TimPost This "Puzzle"/problem could have same serious technical solutions. The explanation of problem is very clear - it was need to reduce multi module loading times and memory consumption - it very valuable thing in any web program. As author I think better is to delete questions than review if it not fit to share.

Comment: @Chameleon I have some Python chops, but some of the other moderators have much stronger Python chops. I don't think anything has to be done immediately. I like the question, It just needs to be a better fit for SO or a sister site. If you flat out want it gone, flag it and I'll delete it. I'd recommend waiting a little while other people have a look at it though. To reiterate, I don't have a problem with the quality of the question. Right now the issue is square peg -> round hole.

Comment: @CodyGray **Not looking** for re-open votes at all but want to learn how constructive will be your judgement and what suggestion you share. I was put question since think it is **valuable for others** if not I will delete it and not share more knowledge. Content of question is not matter phrasing or attitude but any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: @TimPost I think you want more or less suggest me to reformat content to fit/improve StackOverflow and belive that it not fits currently?

Comment: @Chameleon: I tried rephrasing your question (with an edit) into what I think is a better fit for SO. If you don't like the edit, you can roll it back.

Comment: BTW--If you like to pose or solve programming puzzle, you can checkout [CodeGolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), though you should be aware that we have some rules about what makes a good puzzle there (objective winning criterion, more than one way to approach it, preferably applicable to multiple languages, etc...).

Comment: @Mat It looks better and is the best constructive thing which was done! Now I will not delete question since it will be waste of our both effort :)

Comment: @CodyGray downvoting for arrogant tone **may** be **sometimes** appropriate on Meta.SE, but clearly not on SO. The aspects that are emotional instead of meritorical can be simply edited out.

Answer (score 9):

I was responsible for the fourth close vote. Let my clarify my stand.

While I had my doubts that it solves the root of the problem, I did find your *valuable code* interesting (or else I would simply have moved on and not bothered to communicating with your over the last 16 hours!).

The technical content was not why I cast the close vote. As I have  tried to explain in the comments (and obviously failed), **the question in its current form is not a good fit for the site**. To put in bluntly, it is currently along the lines of *"I have this brilliant solution, can you do better?"*. That's more a blog post than an entry in a QA site.

Had you reformulated it as *"I'm trying to solve X. I've tried doing Y and it seems ok. Any suggestions for improving this?"* I would have upvoted and given it a shot.

p.s. I did consider editing the question and trying to get the question reopened. Based on past experience, this often works. However, the defensive self-assured tone of your comments put me off and I doubt you would have liked me "butchering" your question.

p.p.s Just notice [Mat's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9381555/4) and it seems workable. Voting to re-open.

Comment: I think that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381555/how-to-avoid-latencies-with-python-module-globals-initialization more people focusing om **reformatting** than on answering - nice to have good content but better has heart of users :)

Mat's edit is nice++ and is very constructive and it seems workable as you said!

Comment: @Chameleon A good question in a bad form might look as a bad question, and viceversa. Nice justification you got there with the "heart" thing, but don't underestimate the importance of how the content is presented; you pretty much had just had an example of this, aknowledge that

Comment: I've re-opened the question based on the edit, with an up-vote to boot. @Mat - thank you for being awesome. Glad this came to a swift and favorable resolution :)

Comment: @Chameleon Well posed questions attract good questions as evident throughout the site.  Yes, content is important, which is why the community moderates and collaboratively edit what is on the site. If you get the impression that you only receive negative responses from the community, perhaps you should reevaluate your approach to asking questions and interacting with others.

Comment: @ShawnChin Your all overlay suggestion is valuable - if will be not better answer I will vote for this - your suggestion will have impact on interaction with people and StackOverflow :)

I am has experience in content management so understand your effort to keep it clean but consider my suggestion that "clean" mean different thing for **heart of programmer/project/product manager** (100 000++ lines of code) or heart of user (1 000++ line of code) ... - is like 100/1 - more people like Mat less "moderation"!